# Flutter - A RenderFlex overflowed by 29 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, col

I have table, which is cut on right - there are some more of columns and it does not fit on the moblie screen. Of this reason I get an error: A RenderFlex overflowed by 29 pixels on the right.

How to enable scrolling horizontally?

My table looks something like this. On the right side there are other columns, e.g. ddd, eee, ff etc, which do not fit on the screen. There is cannot scroll right.

[image]

My code:

```
class _SimpleTableState extends State<SimpleTable> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: initHeader(),
      rows: initRows(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping 'SingleChildScrollView' widget and set 'scrollDirection' to 'Axis.horizontal.

And if you have many rows, you need vertical scroll someday.

```
class _SimpleTableState extends State<SimpleTable> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: DataTable(
        columns: initHeader(),
        rows: initRows(),
      ),
    );
  }
...
```

Comment: Thank you :) There is possible to set horizontal and vertical scroll together?

Comment: Yes. If widget.items's count is big in your source, vertical overflow problem will be occurred.

Comment: But if I add more rows then I can scroll down also. So is it okay?

Comment: Oh~ This means that DataTable widget supports vertical scroll itself. If that, okay!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it with `listview` or `SingleChildScrollView`and set`scrollDirection` to horizontal like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       child: DataTable()
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the Table widget ([Table class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html))